# Derive Unit Vector from Rotation Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have a rotation vector

```
<45.0, 45.0, 45.0>
```

Up Vector:

```
<0.0, 1.0, 0.0>
```

How can i get a unit vector representation of the rotation vector? Basically i want to see which direction an object is looking at.

I might have wrong impression of the correct naming, please feel free to correct my question.

Comment: Actually a 3-d rotation only needs 3 parameters: a unit vector (which can be specified by 2 components, since the third component comes from the fact that it has unit length) and a rotation angle.  Or even better, it can be represented by a bivector, which has 3 components, and represents the plane of rotation and the angle more naturally.

Comment: The Rotation Vector represent a rotation in 3D-Space. Lets say a cube. and My Z Axis is the looking direction.  When this object gets rotated, i would like to represent the rotation as a vector, to see "where it is facing"

Comment: Is `45.0` an angle or a distance?

Comment: its an angle, ...

Comment: @user1767754 What angles? in what order? You really need to be specific about what you are talking about since there are $75\frac12$ ways to represent rotations with a list of 3 numbers.

Comment: @MattDickau You're right: I had a lapse and forgot that the fourth parameter in, say, a quaternion representation, is bundled up with the other three. What I really wanted to get to the bottom of is what the user's interpretation of the three numbers is. Unfortunately the OP's response invalidate the two existing answers...

Comment: @user1767754 Maybe take a look at [Axis-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) and [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) representations of rotations and let us know which one you are using the specify the rotation...

Answer (score 2):

If $\vec{z} = (45,45,45)$ then the unit direction is simply

$$ \hat{z} = \frac{(45,45,45)}{\|(45,45,45)\|} =( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$$

Now with the up direction $\hat{y} = (0,1,0)$ you can find the *x*-axis direction with

$$ \vec{x} = \vec{y} \times \vec{z} \\ \hat{x} = \frac{\vec{x}}{\| \vec{x} \|} = ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) $$

<sub>NOTE: $\times$ is the vector cross product</sub>

Comment: is the 1/sqrt(2) example or why are you taking the sqrt of 2?

Comment: The triple $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$ form the unit axis in the rotated coordinate frame. The components is what comes out given the up and _z_ vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to find a unit vector from any vector is by performing scalar division on it. Let $\vec v$ be your so-called "rotation vector", and $\vec w$ be the unit vector. To change the magnitude of a vector, we can use the scalar multiplication and division operations. The vector $a$  divided by some scalar $s$ has a magnitude $||a||/s$. Similarly, the vector $\vec v$ divided by it's magnitude $||\vec v||$  is equal to $||\vec v|| / ||\vec v||$, or $1$. Recall that a vector of length 1 is a unit vector. This means the vector $\vec v / ||\vec v||$ has a magnitude of 1.

Also remember that the scalar multiplication and division operations do not affect the direction of the vector, but only it's length. So if a vector of length 1 is heading the same direction of another vector, it is considered a unit vector of that direction.

**TL;DR: The unit vector with the direction of some "rotation vector" $\mathbf{\vec v}$ is equal to the vector divided by it's magnitude, or**

$$\frac{\vec v}{||v||}$$